Display Data values on top of bar chart using angularJs
I am trying to dispay a barchart using chartjs and angularjs by getting data from database i am succesful in doing it but when i hover on the bar then the values are displayed i want the values to be displayed on top of Bar.
My angularjs code-
  $scope.labelsFamilyAge = [" 60 to 64", " 65 to 70", " 71 to 75"," 76 to 80", "81 to 85", "86 to 90", "91 to 95","96 to 100", "100"];

         $scope.get_data = [];
              $scope.GET_Data = function () {
                 $scope.getdata = [];
                   var GetRc = new Object();
                   var httprequest = $http({
                     method: 'POST',
                 url: API_URL + GetDBdata,
                        data: GetRc
               }).then(function (data) {
                   $scope.get_data = data.data.Data[0];
                  angular.forEach($scope.get_data, function (values) {
                $scope.getdaata.push(values);
                    $scope.totaldata += values;
                       })
                      $scope.ctrloptions = {
                       legend: {
                         display: true,
                      position: "bottom"
                     },
                    tooltipEvents: [],
                     showTooltips: true,
                     tooltipCaretSize: 0,
                  onAnimationComplete: function () {
                     this.showTooltip(this.segments, true);
                    }, }; }); }

   my HTML-   <canvas  id="bardata" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="getdaata"                       
    chart-option="ctrloptions" chart-labels="labelsFamilyAge"></canvas>

My data is displayed when i hover on particular bar but i want it to be displayed on top of the bar chart like this.
Bar chart with data on top](https://i.sstatic.net/IxyQLX1W.png)
     I tried with changing chart-options but it didnt work.

     Please provide suggestion how can i achive this.`

